# Bing Speech REST API errors occur

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

When I call the bing speech rest api a few days ago, I get an error and do not return a result.

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at SpeechRESTSample.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\kaki1\Source\Repos\Cognitive-Speech-STT-ServiceLibrary\sample\SpeechRESTSample\Program.cs:line 78
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
Renewed token.

or Internal Server Error

Does not provide services?

Comment: `Renewed token.or Internal Server Error.Does not provide services?`

 I am following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-csharp-dotnet-windows) to test the Speech Rest API, It works correctly for me. If possible, please share the demo code.

Comment: @TomSun If you test using SpeechClient, it will work normally. The service in error is the REST service. Here are the source links i tested. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-REST

Answer (score 1):

If I use the sample code directly to get the token then I got the 401 error.

The `FetchTokenUri` is changed from `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0` to

```
https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken
```

we could get the authentication endpoint from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis#authentication).

And the [endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis#text-to-speech) for the Speech to Text REST API is the following format

```
https://{region}.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1
```

I also test it locally I can get the token with the  endpoint.

For more demo code, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis#renew-authorization).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I'll check.

Comment: By the way, I want to use is the Bing Speech service (Bing Speech service and Speech service are different services). Speech service does not support Korean. So, I completed the implementation using Bing Speech Service SDK and WebSocket. I will add a comment when I solve a problem in the future Bing Speech REST API. Thank you